# Any system call in C to change the permission of a file in HP-UX

Tags: c, hp-ux

Any system call in  C to change the permission of a file  in HP-UX??

Answer (score 4):

See `chmod` ([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html)) in `sys/stat.h`.  The example below comes from the documentation.  HP-UX is POSIX compliant so you can use those functions as well as standard functions from the C library.

> The following example sets the file permission bits for a file named /home/cnd/mod1, then calls the stat() function to verify the permissions.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int status;
struct stat buffer
...
chmod("home/cnd/mod1", S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
status = stat("home/cnd/mod1", &buffer;);
```

Comment: Hi Jeff,  Thanks for your reply. When i run the program as SU the chmod is working. But when i run it as a non-root user, chmod is failing and returning -1. I need it to work in non-root user mode, what should i do???...

Comment: Hi jeff, i think setuid will work. but i don't know how to use it in this context. do u ve any idea of how to use it???

Comment: Not without context, answering another question in the comments of this question doesn't seem like a great idea.  Why don't you take a look at opening a new question with a better description of your problem?